Probabilty of Rotating Finite Rod hitting 3 oranges
Imagine the Cartesian 2-D plane but it's cut off, [the plane goes to $(100,100)$ from $(-100,-100)$ with $(100,-100)$ and $(-100,100)$ as other vertice's so as to be a finite square].
Now there is a line initially having the equation $y=x$ and at $t=o$ this line starts to rotate about the origin with angular velocity $1/3$ rad per $t$ unit.
Imagine there spawn nine distinct oranges on the plane such that they only spawn on lattice points and the objective is "completed" if the line $y=x$ hits $3$ oranges all at once during its rotation. After every rotation the positions of oranges change randomly but never overlap each other.

Based on this:
a.) What is the probability that line completes the objective on first revolution.
b.) How long do we wait to make sure that there is at least a 50% chance that the line completes its objective.
My attempt for a.) I tried to form triplets of 3 spaces for which we could pick 3 oranges  from 9 for the oranges to spawn. For the total number triplets there are $(200)^2(200^2-1)(200^2-2)$ possible combinations but for $3$ triples in a row I am unable to derive the number of possible combinations and since question b depends on this I was unable to work on it too.

Please use MathJax, even if they're simple equations. Also, can you draw a picture to visualize this problem easier?

@OscarNguyen i think i could post an image, how does one do so in the comments.

actually you can upload it on your question

If you are speaking about a "finite square" why not just write out the four vertices?  We can't guess which square you mean from just two vertices.  Even guessing that you want those two vertices to form a side of the square (and not a diagonal), there would be two options.

And what does it mean to "spawn" oranges?  Are you just saying that there are $9$ objects on lattice points? How are they located?  Uniformly at random (given that the locations are distinct)? Something else?  And sometimes it is $9$ and sometimes it is $5$...Please edit your post for clarity.

Hint 1: what does it mean (in terms of their coordinates) for three points to be collinear with the origin? You should be able to use this to get an answer to the first question (call the probability of hitting the oranges $p$). Hint 2: the game resets each time. The probability of not having hit after one revolution is $1-p$; after two, it's $(1-p)^2$, and so on. That should answer the second question.

@JeanMarie fixed it!.

@lulu fixed the vertices issues, yes the oranges randomly spawn on lattice points after every rotation of the rod. I hope the edit is clear now!!

For b), if how long refers to how many complete revolutions needed, then the angular velocity looks like less relevant to me as it is just a unit problem - in terms of the number of complete revolutions, or in terms of time. If OP have some implication that the rotation stop as long as the objective is completed the first time, then we need to consider the position of the oranges as well and the starting orientation - to account for the incomplete revolution. But even in such case we can in terms of how many radian, the angular displacement anyway.

@BGM     Since each revolution takes 6(pie) seconds the number of revolutions here would let us know the time it took for the event to occur with p>0.5 ,
as a side note i dont know what to do now that the question has lost all traction, do we just wait..?

@Scypher_Tzu re your side note, did you get anywhere with the hints I suggested above?
